# Your site has no hreflang tags. International Targeting Language Issue

Tags: meta-tags, google-search-console

I'm trying to remove this issue from my website but unable to do it. I have tried this tag

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.website.com" hreflang="en" />
```

but it's not working here is the link of my website [Site](http://www.kashiflatif.info/)

Comment: <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.kashiflatif.info" hreflang="en-US" /> .. Try This..

Comment: in href I should type complete URL?

Comment: yupp ... `href="http://www.kashiflatif.info"`

Comment: done, so how much time google webmaster will take to check it? suddenly or after some days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your href :** 
`href="http://www.kashiflatif.info"`

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.kashiflatif.info" hreflang="en-US"/>
```

> NOTE: maybe google webmaster will take some time to check it. ( 24 to 48 hours approx  )

**Reference:**

1. https://moz.com/learn/seo/hreflang-tag
2. https://yoast.com/hreflang-ultimate-guide/

Comment: still waiting for approval

Comment: Sorry.. ... It's take 24 to 48 hours approximately :)

Comment: yup actually the issue was with days, i was writing the same tag but i did not wait for 2 days :) and now it's working fine

Comment: hreflang="en" is valid?

Comment: @BecarioSenior Yes its !!